# R shiny renderLeaflet not rendering

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, maps

I am trying to create an interactive map that displays locations only in the district chosen by the user in R shiny.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

setwd("C:/Users/Dulguun Sukhbat/Desktop/intern")
data <- read_xlsx("data.xlsx",sheet = 1)
data <- data %>% select(-c(total.price,location,"location:"))
data <- na.omit(data)
attach(data)
data$LAT <- as.numeric(data$LAT)
data$LONG <- as.numeric(data$LONG)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("district","Select a district:",
                  choices = unique(data$district))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Map")
      )
    )
  )
)
#server <- function(input, output) {
 # dist_choice <- reactive({
    #d <- data %>% filter(district == input$district)
   # return(d)
 # })
  #dist_choice <- dist_choice %>% mutate(popup_info=paste("built - ",built,"<br/>","area - ",
  #                                         square,"<br/>","sq.price - ",sq.price))
 # }
server <- function(input, output) {
  dist_choice <- reactive({
    data %>%
      filter(district %in% input$district) %>%
      mutate(popup_info = paste("built - ",built,"<br/>","area - ",
                          square,"<br/>","sq.price - ",sq.price))
  })
  output$Map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(dist_choice()) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(data = dist_choice(),
                        lat = ~LAT,lng = ~LONG,radius=1,popup = ~popup_info)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

There is no error message when I run the app, but the map doesn't show up. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include minimal reproducible example as data you use is not available for us (you can check function `dput` for this). But it looks that you just missed output function in UI.

Here:

```
mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Map")
      )
    )
```

You create `mainPanel`, then `tabsetPanel` as a place where `tabPanel`s will live. And then `tabPanel`, but it is just a `tab`, you still need to tell that there you want to have your map. You can also run `?tabPanel` to see examples in documentation.

It should be:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Map",
             leafletOutput("Map")
             )
  )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time asking a question here. Your answer solved the problem. Much appreciated.